# How to light a video properly?

Tags: video, lighting, budget

I need to light a video for a project, I am making a movie trailer for a book I like and need to light a large space (It is an action book and there is running in the trailer.) Simply, I have to light an action video and I don't want to spend lots of money on this one project. Also, if there is a program that can edit the lighting and contrast after you record, please tell. So how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For action, you're probably going to need flat, even lighting. Builders' work lamps, bounced off white walls or reflectors, are probably the most cost-effective way of lighting large spaces.

You can make some changes to lighting and contrast when you edit, though it's no substitute for lighting your film properly. It's called colour correction. You can also apply an overall colour 'look' to your film, which is called grading. Most editing programs (e.g. iMovie) allow you to apply basic effects and corrections. Programs like Final Cut Pro X, the <strike>open source</strike> Da Vinci Resolve (free lite version), and (steep learning curve) Adobe After Effects let you do professional correction and grading.

Comment: I have a work lamp, but is there a way to make a deflector? If you know a video that specifically talks about lighting large spaces, please tell.

Comment: Pretty sure Da Vinci Resolve isn't open source.  The lite version is free, however.

Comment: Yeah, Da Vinci costs about $1K if you want the full version.

Comment: A reflector can be made out of literally anything white. Popular cheapo reflectors include polystyrene sheets, bedsheets hung from walls, pieces of white cardboard, and white walls.

Comment: All of those are good ideas. You can also buy affordable folding five-in-one reflector/diffusers which are more convenient to carry around.

Answer (score 0):

You could visit [this](http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/5-diy-lighting-tips-for-filmmakers-on-a-budget/) website for some DIY video's to set-up your own film lighting and [this](http://learnaboutfilm.com/making-a-film/equipment-for-low-budget-filmmaking/lighting-low-budget-filmmaking/) website for some more information about which lights to use.

You should also make a thoughtful decision on the camera/lens you are about to use. More info can be found [here.](http://learnaboutfilm.com/making-a-film/equipment-for-low-budget-filmmaking/filmmakingcamera/)